# PHP \xf0 representa 0xF0?

Tags: php, string, hexadecimal, byte

Se `\xF0` representa um hexa assim como `0xF0`, porque a saída deles é diferente?

```
echo "\xF0";
echo 0xF0;
```

Na verdade não encontro informação nenhuma sobre essa notação `\xF0` no manual do PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

São coisas diferentes. O primeiro exemplo é uma string, e a notação de escape `\xHH` representa o código hexadecimal de um caractere. Já o `0xF0` é um número, inteiro, representado como hexadecimal literal (ou seja, base 16). Então no primeiro caso o código hexadecimal representa um caractere de uma tabela, enquanto no segundo caso ele é simplesmente um número.

Comment: Ei e no seguinte código: >>> privkey = os.urandom(32)
>>> print(privkey)
b'\x9a\xfbch\x05\xc3|\xdf\xfc\xebJ\x89g' ? Isso não pode ser hexa ou pode de alguma forma? O código acima é python

Comment: Isso parece uma string